# Interpretation of cox regression summary with more than 2 coefficients

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

```
                        coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)    
hypertensionPresent 0.417717  1.518491 0.209708 1.992   0.0464 *  
age                 0.042424  1.043336 0.008693 4.880 1.06e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

                    exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
hypertensionPresent     1.518     0.6585     1.007     2.290
age                     1.043     0.9585     1.026     1.061
```

I know that for the summary above, two things that can be said are:

1. At a given instance in time, someone who has hypertension is 52% more likely to die as someone without hypertension, adjusting for age.
2. At any given instance in time, someone who does *not* have
   hypertension is 34%  less likely (0.66) to die as someone who does,
   adjusting for age.

But what can be said about an output which has many coefficients?

Am I correct in thinking that for hypertension, let's say, the way to interpret that would be "for any particular time, hypertensive participants are 1.64 times more likely to die compared to non-hypertensive participants, adjusting for age, anemia, etc...".

Meaning, I would have *many* combinations since they'd all be distinct?
(Controlling for the combinations in an n-dimensional way)

```
                         exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
age                         1.0445     0.9574    1.0266     1.063
anaemia1                    1.5621     0.6402    1.0249     2.381
creatinine_phosphokinase    1.0002     0.9998    1.0000     1.000
ejection_fraction           0.9536     1.0486    0.9346     0.973
serum_creatinine            1.3688     0.7306    1.1957     1.567
serum_sodium                0.9553     1.0468    0.9126     1.000
hypertensionPresent         1.6430     0.6086    1.0808     2.498
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation is that across all levels of age, anemia, etc, you will find that hypertensive participants will have 1.64 times the hazard of dying at any given time compared to non-hypertensive participants. It may not be true if there's effect modification/interaction.